# Socket programming + HTTP1.1 in Python

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

The task is building two files client.py and server.py. I am able to connect the client to the server. The problem I encounter is when I trying to send a get request like client.send("bGET /suc.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n"), I do not how to return the file suc.txt to the client from the server side. The scene is a client request file from a server and what the server returns is the respond header and the requested file.

What I wrote so far :

Client:

```
import socket
target_host = "127.0.0.1"
target_port = 5050

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target_host,target_port))
client.send("bGET /suc.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n")
response = client.recv(1024)
print(response.decode())
```

Server:

```
import socket
import threading
import urllib.request

HEADER = 64
PORT = 5050
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST,PORT))

def handleClient(conn, addr):
    print (f"[NEW CONNECTION {addr} connected. ")
    connected = True
    while connected:
        conn.send()

  

def start():
    server.listen()
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handleClient, args=(conn,addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount()} ")


print ("server is starting...")
start()
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> client.send("bGET /suc.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:127.0.0.1\r\n\r\n")
> ```

The `"b..."` should be `b"..."`, i.e. you want to specify a sequence of bytes and not a string with a `b` as first character.

> I do not how to return the file suc.txt to the client from the server side

You basically ask very broadly how to read an HTTP request,  extract information from it, create a proper response and send it. All what you code so far does is create a listener socket, so you are far away from your ultimate goal.

There are two major ways to tackle this: the easy one is to use a library like [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html) to implement the complexity of HTTP for you. The documentation contains actual examples on how to do this and there are many more examples on the internet for this.

The harder option is to study the actual [HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230) and implement everything yourself based on this standard. Expecting that somebody explains the complex standard here and describes how to implement it would be a too broad question.